# Animate elements on .click () using .clone () and .animate ()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There're next HTML:

```
<div class="garden">
    <div class="point left">&#9668;</div>
        <div class="trees">
            <div id="apple">Apple</div>
            <div id="cherry">Cherry</div>
            <div id="pear">Pear</div>
            <div id="oak">Oak</div>
            <div id="fir">Fir</div>
        </div>
    <div class="point right">&#9658;</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.garden { position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 150px; }
.garden > div { display:inline-block; }
.trees { width:550px; height:53px; position:relative; font-size:70%; }
.point { width: 16px; height: 15px; background: url(/point-sprite.png) no-repeat;}
.point.left  { background-position: -16px 0; }
.point:hover { background-position: 0 0; }
.point.right { background-position: -32px 0; }
.point:hover { background-position: -48px 0 }
.trees > div span { min-width:50px; position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:25px; left:15px; text-align:center; }

#apple, #cherry, #pear, #oak, #fir { position: absolute; color: #0094d9; }
#apple { top: 10px; }
#cherry { top: 2px; left: 90px; }
#pear { left: 180px; }
#oak { left: 280px; }
#fir { top: 2px; left: 373px; }
```

I need to change the position of the elements to the left after each clicking "point left". And to the right after each clicking "poin right". When an item has a position of leftmost and click "point left" then this item should go right to the rightmost position. One great man (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2121519/stuart-miller) help me to creat next script:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function changePositionLeft() {

        var trees = $('#trees');

        trees.children().each( function(index, child) {
            if (index == 0) {
                $(child).animate(trees.children().last().position());
            }
            else {
                $(child).animate(trees.children().eq(index - 1).position());
            }
        });

        trees.children().first().appendTo(trees);        
    }

    $(".point.left").click(function() {
        changePositionLeft();
    });
});
```

Help transform it according to my task with using .clone. Thanks in advance
Link for script: http://jsfiddle.net/8kkfw7mu/5/

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What do you mean using clone? It works as is.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. I mean next.  When an item has a position of leftmost and click "point left" then this item is cloned and it should go right to the rightmost position

Comment: Fiddle already does that. What's wrong with the fiddle?

Comment: It's work good. But my task says to use clone. I think it conects wit next.When we click on `point left` we can see how leftmost item is animated to the oisition of last item. But it have to only appeares at this position. My task says: "By clicking on the points button item animated shifted one position to the left or right. By moving the item to the left the copy of leftmost item  moves out (appeares) on the right on the position of rightmost element"

Answer (score 0):

You want us to code the `changePositionRight` function?

If so, [here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/8kkfw7mu/8/).

I kept the same structure as the `changePositionLeft` method, but changed the following:

```
if (index == trees.children().length -1) {
    $(child).animate(trees.children().first().position());
}
```

Instead of targetting the first element and putting it in the last position, we target the last one, and put it in first position.

Then:

```
else {
   $(child).animate(trees.children().eq(index + 1).position());
}
```

Instead of moving the others elements to the previous position, move them to the next position.

### Final result

Add this to your script:

```
function changePositionRight(){
    var trees = $('#trees');
    trees.children().each( function(index, child) {
        if (index == trees.children().length -1) {
            $(child).animate(trees.children().first().position());
        }
        else {
            $(child).animate(trees.children().eq(index + 1).position());
        }
    });

    trees.children().last().appendTo(trees);        
}

$(".point.right").click(function() {
   changePositionRight();
});
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. I mean next. When an item has a position of leftmost and click "point left" then this item is cloned and it should go right to the rightmost position

Comment: But your button targets the whole list, so should the last element always be duplicated or should there be another button to clone?

Comment: There are only two buttons - `point left` and `point right`. When we click button (`point left`) each item takes the position of previous item. But if the item takes the position of leftmost item it is duplicated and its copy appeare at the posiotion of rightmostitem. For example. Image that You clicked on `point left`. Than `cherry` takes the position of `apple`, `pear` takes the position of `cherry`, `oak` takes the position of `pear`, `fir` take the position of `oak`. The `apple` is removed, copy of `apple` is created and its takes the position of `fir`. And so on.